# In asp.net textbox: enter text and it appears instantly in another textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

In asp.net textbox: enter text and it appears instantly in another textbox

any good suggestions?

i need this all over the my web app so it should be more light weighted too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery.

http://jsbin.com/axeko3/2/edit

Hope this helps.

Here is the jQuery code to do this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#box1").keyup(function(){
        $("#box2").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: -1 for making me jump around the web to look at a short snippet of code. Would be a +1 for a good answer if not for that.

Comment: I understand that. I personally prefer the working example and the sandbox that jsbin provides.

Comment: So why not paste the answer in here when done and link jsbin as providing a nice working sandbox of it?

Comment: +1, I don't see how linking to a working copy of the code is somehow not useful. Maybe it would be preferable to post short jQuery code here and link to the jsbin example, but preferable and wrong are two different things. It isn't like rcravens posted an answer using assembly to answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using JavaScript. You save so much resources by doing it in client side.

Use the `onChange` event of `input` element

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaScript, `OnBlur` or `OnChange` access textbox_1 by `document.getElementById` or by `document.getElementByName` and write to other textbox_2 by the same functions.